# how to show the friends of a person base on this table design, is my database design correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

[table person & table friends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqgN1.png) - I have a table called person and friends,

- person has column: id, and name,
- friends has column: ctrl_no, person_id and friend_id

I want to show the name of a friend where person_id = 1, but it shows the name of the person WHERE person_id = 1,

person:

```
person id  |  name     
---------- | ----------
1          |  Jervy
2          |  Pamela Shane
3          |  Hikari
```

friends:

```
ctrl_no    |  person_id     |  friend_id
---------- | -------------  | -----------
1          |  1             |  2
2          |  2             |  1
3          |  1             |  3
4          |  3             |  1
```

I tried my query below

```
SELECT person.name FROM person
JOIN friends ON person.person_id = friends.person_id
WHERE person.person_id = 1;
```

my query shows the name of person where person_id = 1 not his friend's name...

I want show. . . WHERE person.person_id = 1

```
Name
Pamela Shane
Hikari
```

It confusing me now. T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is fine. The query just needs to be like this instead:

```
SELECT person.name FROM person
JOIN friends ON person.person_id = friends.friend_id
WHERE friends.person_id = 1
```

You want the friends' names, so you need to join the person table on `friend_id`. Otherwise you just get the same person's name repeatedly, which I assume is what you're seeing now.

And the criteria needs to check for `friends.person_id` rather than `person.person_id`. Since you want all the rows from that table for that person.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query so you got your tables backwards:

```
SELECT person.name 
FROM friends JOIN person 
ON person.person_id = friends.person_id 
WHERE person.person_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT person.name 
  FROM person
  WHERE person.person_id = 
  (
         SELECT friends.friend_id 
         FROM friends JOIN person 
         ON person.person_id = friends.person_id 
         WHERE person.person_id = 1
    )`